# GCC Graphite - 4.8 loops optimizations

Tags: loops, optimization, gcc4.8

I am working on a C++ simulation framework. In the current version, I identified two bottlenecks. The first one is Random number generating, and second one (which motivates this question) is the use of highly iterative processes (heavy `for loops`).

Does some of you could give me a feedback on gcc 4.8 concerning loops optimization.

I have read some of the few available literature on the subject but, may be you can make more explicit to me (with more simple words), what I can expect from this early version.

What do one call `loop normalization`, for example... Or what does it has to do with multi-core architecture...

Also, what is behind the optimization options :

> -ftree-loop-optimize
>       Perform loop optimizations on trees. This flag is enabled by default at -O and higher.
>
> -ftree-loop-linear
>       Perform loop interchange transformations on tree. Same as -floop-interchange. To use this code transformation, GCC has to be configured with --with-ppl and --with-cloog to enable the Graphite loop transformation infrastructure.
>
> -floop-interchange
>       Perform loop interchange transformations on loops. Interchanging two nested loops switches the inner and outer loops.

Any code optimization and/or compiler experts over there ?
Thanks a lot.

NB : I currently work under Debian 4.7.2, gcc 4.7

Comment: Better ask on `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`; you may want to use *OpenMP* pragmas.

Comment: Yes thanks, I'll do that, but I was looking for, how to say, a smooth entrance into the subject. And may be basic experience feedbacks on simple use cases.

Comment: Try first `gcc -mtune=native -O3`; anything more requires a lot of knowledge.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the starting point. I will dig in that direction first...

Comment: You might try -funroll-loops

Comment: Well, I'm not at it currently, but that sounds interesting. I'll give it a try. Thank you.